# Spring Batch: How to access the current step's id / name from within an ItemReader or ItemWriter

Tags: java, spring, batch-processing, spring-batch

I am quite new to **Spring-Batch** and I wonder whether there is a way to **access the step-id** from within an ItemReader or ItemWriter?

*In my case that would allow switching enum types based on different step-definitions in a single ItemReader implementation.*

Does anyone know a way to do that?

Comment: May the BeanNameAware interface be enough?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Assuming the ItemReader or ItemWriter are step scoped, you can do this:

```
<bean id="flatFileItemReader" scope="step"
      class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemReader">
    <property name="resource" value="#{stepExecution.stepName}" />
</bean>
```

Comment: Thank you. That would be sufficient most of the time. In my special case the beforeStep-method came to rescue as i needed to access the StepExecution right before i open the ItemStream ... Thank you for the great work on Spring-batch by the way. I do really appreciate it! Wish you a happy 2014!

Answer (score 3):

It is as simple as implementing a with `@BeforeStep` annotated method:

```
@BeforeStep
public void beforeStep(StepExecution stepExecution){
    String name = stepExecution.getStepName();
    System.out.println("name: " + name);
}
```

Placed it in my **ItemReader** and that's it ...