# Extend partitioning to one more level

Tags: java, spring-batch

As per below image from [Spring Batch Doc](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/reference/html/scalability.html#partitioning), A master step is getting partitioned into Six Slave steps which are identical copies of master.

[image]

My question is, can I extend partitioning to one more level or N more levels? i.e. All of six slaves becomes a master for further N slaves?

**Use Case:** First we partition data on major criteria then we further partition data on some other criteria with in that major criteria.

e.g. first I launch slaves for data of N clients based on **client name** then for each client name, partition data further based on **office locations**.

Can this be done or not supported?

**EDIT:** As per my coding experiments, it doesn't look doable due to `StepExecutionContext` issues. [See this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21112446/spring-batch-field-or-property-stepexecutioncontext-cannot-be-found) and [this](http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/batch/105463-illegalstateexception-no-context-holder-available-for-step-scope). We can't pass `StepExecutionContext` from one `Step` to another in partitioning context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(I should have asked more details, so my answer might be unecessarily long, depending on what you understand from partitionning in spring-batch. I'll keep this thread if I need to use partitionning).

You could always spawn your own threads from your slaves and give them the parameters they need, but that would completely defeat the whole point of using a framework like spring-batch.

This is not a direct solution to your problem: slaves don't spawn other slaver here. And in fact, and I don't think they should/can. But the `Partitionner` you make will simulate this behavior by giving each slaves it's own parameters (clientName and officeLocation) in their ExecutionContext, so they'll read/process/write their own part.

---

If you didn't understood:

I'm using this as an example: https://www.mkyong.com/spring-batch/spring-batch-partitioning-example/ so you'll need to read to know what I'm sayin.

From what I understand of partitionning, each step will have its own ExecutionContext, and in this context you'll put what parameter is specific to each slaves. You'll need to create a Partitionner that sets the specific values for each slave from the gridSize.

In Mkyong's example, he sets the value of gridSize to 10, which mean he'll have 10 threads. He knows he will go from 1 to 100, so he sets for each threads the database value matching:

```
for `thread1`, fromId:1 toId:10, 
for `thread2`, fromId:11 toId:20, 
for `thread3`, fromId:21 toId:30, 
etc.
```

He sets these values in the `ExecutionContext`, so each reader/processor/writer gets their own value for their processing (the selects goes from `fromId`to `toId`, so each selects gets it's own part). If he wanted, he could have done something more dynamic: set the total number of ids of the database in the `Partitionner` and change the `toId` and `fromId` depending on the size. It's highly customisable.

For your case, it's like you have to take care of two parameters (here it was just the id), and they're not numbers. Let's say you only had `clientName`, if you give your Partitionner a list (or array) of these client name, you'll just have to spawn one `ExecutionContext` per `clientName` and set it in. If you have two parameters, you could use a more complex structure, like a `List` of `Client` class (and of course, each `Client` have a `clientName` parameter and a list of String `officeLocations`). Now, you'll create one `ExecutionContext` per `clientName` per `officeLocation`.Each reader will get from its ExecutionContext what `clientName` and `officeLocation` to select them.

For example, if you have 3 clients and each has 2 locations, you'll end up with 6 ExecutionContext (and so, 6 slaves/threads). Then, on your `Reader` you'll just have to retreive the clientName and officeName from the `ExecutionContext` and use them to select your entities (from DB or whatever).

Creating the list of clients with their officeName could be done in a previous step and set in the job context to be accesible in the whole job. If the gridSize needs to be the same as the number of threads created by spring batch, you can calculate it at the same moment you create your list of clients and set it the same way.

Comment: I can't run slave step based on combined key - `clientName +officeLocations` but only `clientName` because `writer` of this partitioned step is basically a Lucene Index Writer and same instance of writer can write indices to a single directory in multi threaded way but two different writers can't write to a single directory.I already have a working job based on partitions for `clientName`. `clientName`further translates to directory where Lucene stores its indices.

Comment: Well I've been thinking about that and I think that by default, you can't really do that, beacuse spring-batch's multi-threading is at step level. You could still manager each of your writer in a factory/registry rather than in Spring batch. Each `clientName+officeLocations` writers will have access to its `clientName` writer through this registry, and they'll call the write on it in a syncrhonized way. Depending on read/process/write speed, it might be faster to manage custom threads in the processors, but it might also be more complicated.